# Accessibilit on VIM - Is it possible to play sounds on actions?

Tags: vim, accessibility, neovim

I'm visually impaired (legally blind, but I can still see a little) and would like to know if there is a possibility to play sounds when performing certain actions in VIM so I don't need to move the screen around too much (I need 9x magnification in order to see, so...)

Examples:

- Play `01.wav` sound when writing file with `:w`
- Play `02.wav` sound when `:set number` is activated
- Play `03.wav` sound when entering INSERT mode
- Play `04.wav` sound when entering VISUAL mode
- etc...

Maybe this information is useful:

I'm using:

- MacOSX 10.14 (Mojave)
- VIM 9
- Neovim 0.8
- Terminal.app (bash)
- iTerm 2

Thank you all for your attention

I haven't try anything yet. I'm really new to VIM.

Comment: Neovim has a fairly robust remote API with some sort of event publish/subscribe mechanism. Perhaps this would be sufficient to implement this sort of feature. It's probably worth exploring the documentation to see what's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to play sound has been added to Vim between 8.2 and 9.0 but the default Vim on macOS is not built with that feature and I have no idea if Neovim merged it in the mean time. This means that you will probably have to get your hands on a proper build.

The following works in the latest [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) build, `r176` at the time of writing.

Now, on to the good stuff…

Vim has that notion of "autocommand", introduced in section 40 of the user manual, `:help 40.3`, and further documented under `:help autocommand`. You can think of it as an event listener/handler combo that allows you to do something when a given event is triggered. Autocommands are very often used for… running a linter automatically on write, changing the value of an option when switching modes, overriding parts of a colorscheme, etc. The full list of events is under `:help autocommand-events`.

Taking your first use case as example:

> Play `01.wav` sound when writing file with `:w`

we can use:

- an autocommand for the general "Do X when Y happens" usage pattern,
- the `:help BufWritePost` event for the "when writing file with `:w`",
- the `*` pattern because you didn't specify any filename restriction,
- the `:help sound_playfile()` function for the "Play `01.wav` sound".

It should look something like this:

```
augroup mySounds
    autocmd!
    autocmd! BufWritePost * call sound_playfile('/absolute/path/to/01.wav')
augroup END
```

To be honest, my initial reaction when that feature was added was a big WTF, but your question kind of made me change my mind. Generalizing this and packaging it as a plugin sounds like a good idea.